# Scale image to fit available space, while preventing cropping

Tags: html, css, layout

I have a fixed-height container with two divs, one on top of the other.

The top div contains an image.

The bottom div contains a variable amount of text. The more text, the taller this bottom div, and the shorter the top div becomes.

As the top div expands or shrinks, I want the image to scale gracefully such that

- it maintains its aspect ratio,
- it does not get cropped
- it never exceeds its intrinsic height/width

Any thoughts on best approach? Here's the code I have so far.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-vz3xhh

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max-width:100%;` to the img attribute. and the image you mentioned here  is very small in size so the image is not fit to the container,you can change and try the image.

```css
.container {
              border: 2px solid red;
              height: 402px;
              display: flex;
              flex-direction: column;
              justify-content: flex-end;
            }
            .container div {
              border: 5px dashed green;
            }
            .container div:first-child {
              max-width:100%;
              height: 100%;
              background-image: url(https://content3.jdmagicbox.com/comp/noida/p7/011pxx11.xx11.170809044019.f8p7/catalogue/sahoo-ji-veg-mart-noida-0gmaal31ny.jpg?clr=4f3917);
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              background-position: center;
              
            }
            .container div:last-child {
              align-self: flex-end;
            }
            img.example1 {

              height: 100%;
              position: absolute;
              top:50%;
              left:50%;
              transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div></div>
      <div>
        Bacon ipsum dolor amet beef ribs ham hock picanha strip steak hamburger
        Bacon ipsum dolor amet beef ribs ham hock picanha strip steak hamburger
        Bacon ipsum dolor amet beef ribs ham hock picanha strip steak hamburger
        Bacon ipsum dolor amet beef ribs ham hock picanha strip steak hamburger
        burgdoggen shankle. Doner sirloin sausage, tenderloin burgdoggen
        prosciutto pastrami jerky pancetta chislic drumstick beef andouille
        flank pork belly. shankle. Doner sirloin sausage, tenderloin burgdoggen
        prosciutto pastrami jerky pancetta chislic drumstick beef andouille
        flank pork belly shankle. Doner sirloin sausage, tenderloin burgdoggen
        prosciutto pastrami jerky pancetta chislic drumstick beef andouille
        prosciutto pastrami jerky pancetta chislic drumstick beef andouille
        flank pork belly shankle. Doner sirloin sausage, tenderloin burgdoggen
        prosciutto pastrami jerky pancetta chislic drumstick beef andouille
        prosciutto pastrami jerky pancetta chislic drumstick beef andouille
        flank pork belly shankle. Doner sirloin sausage, tenderloin burgdoggen
        prosciutto pastrami jerky pancetta chislic drumstick beef andouille
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks @srinithi R for taking the time on this, but the image is still getting cropped in your solution. I would like for the image to *not* get cropped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `background-position: cover;` and it won't crop the background image. I suggest using larger or higher-res images because there is not really a way to scale the aspect ratio in CSS. Especially when your container has a 100%; width, I would make sure the image is large. Give this a try!.

```css
.container {
              border: 2px solid red;
              height: 402px;
              display: flex;
              flex-direction: column;
              justify-content: flex-end;
            }
            .container div {
              border: 5px dashed green;
            }
            .container div:first-child {
              max-width:100%;
              height: 100%;
              background-image: url('https://content3.jdmagicbox.com/comp/noida/p7/011pxx11.xx11.170809044019.f8p7/catalogue/sahoo-ji-veg-mart-noida-0gmaal31ny.jpg?clr=4f3917');
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              background-position: center;
              background-size: cover;
              
            }
            .container div:last-child {
              align-self: flex-end;
            }
            img.example1 {

              height: 100%;
              position: absolute;
              top:50%;
              left:50%;
              transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div></div>
      <div>
        Bacon ipsum dolor amet beef ribs ham hock picanha strip steak hamburger
        Bacon ipsum dolor amet beef ribs ham hock picanha strip steak hamburger
        Bacon ipsum dolor amet beef ribs ham hock picanha strip steak hamburger
        Bacon ipsum dolor amet beef ribs ham hock picanha strip steak hamburger
        burgdoggen shankle. Doner sirloin sausage, tenderloin burgdoggen
        prosciutto pastrami jerky pancetta chislic drumstick beef andouille
        flank pork belly. shankle. Doner sirloin sausage, tenderloin burgdoggen
        prosciutto pastrami jerky pancetta chislic drumstick beef andouille
        flank pork belly shankle. Doner sirloin sausage, tenderloin burgdoggen
        prosciutto pastrami jerky pancetta chislic drumstick beef andouille
        prosciutto pastrami jerky pancetta chislic drumstick beef andouille
        flank pork belly shankle. Doner sirloin sausage, tenderloin burgdoggen
        prosciutto pastrami jerky pancetta chislic drumstick beef andouille
        prosciutto pastrami jerky pancetta chislic drumstick beef andouille
        flank pork belly shankle. Doner sirloin sausage, tenderloin burgdoggen
        prosciutto pastrami jerky pancetta chislic drumstick beef andouille
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:** Example with a higher-res image.

```css
.container {
              border: 2px solid red;
              height: 402px;
              display: flex;
              flex-direction: column;
              justify-content: flex-end;
            }
            .container div {
              border: 5px dashed green;
            }
            .container div:first-child {
              max-width:100%;
              height: 100%;
              background-image: url('https://ag.utah.gov/wp-content/uploads/2021/06/foodhub-e1623956166619.png');
              background-repeat: no-repeat;
              background-position: center;
              background-size: cover;
              
            }
            .container div:last-child {
              align-self: flex-end;
            }
            img.example1 {

              height: 100%;
              position: absolute;
              top:50%;
              left:50%;
              transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
            }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div></div>
      <div>
        Bacon ipsum dolor amet beef ribs ham hock picanha strip steak hamburger
        Bacon ipsum dolor amet beef ribs ham hock picanha strip steak hamburger
        Bacon ipsum dolor amet beef ribs ham hock picanha strip steak hamburger
        Bacon ipsum dolor amet beef ribs ham hock picanha strip steak hamburger
        burgdoggen shankle. Doner sirloin sausage, tenderloin burgdoggen
        prosciutto pastrami jerky pancetta chislic drumstick beef andouille
        flank pork belly. shankle. Doner sirloin sausage, tenderloin burgdoggen
        prosciutto pastrami jerky pancetta chislic drumstick beef andouille
        flank pork belly shankle. Doner sirloin sausage, tenderloin burgdoggen
        prosciutto pastrami jerky pancetta chislic drumstick beef andouille
        prosciutto pastrami jerky pancetta chislic drumstick beef andouille
        flank pork belly shankle. Doner sirloin sausage, tenderloin burgdoggen
        prosciutto pastrami jerky pancetta chislic drumstick beef andouille
        prosciutto pastrami jerky pancetta chislic drumstick beef andouille
        flank pork belly shankle. Doner sirloin sausage, tenderloin burgdoggen
        prosciutto pastrami jerky pancetta chislic drumstick beef andouille
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```